# Quick Rock, Paper, Scissors game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how to know which button the person playing the game pressed because as of right now I have the values one by one, can I add the function and event listener to all three buttons or I was thinking maybe like a nodelist of the buttons and `forEach` them adding the functions.

```js
const rock = document.querySelector('.rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('.paper');
const scissor = document.querySelector('.scissor');
const resetButton = document.querySelector('.reset');
const whoWonTheRound = document.querySelector('#log');
const computerLog = document.querySelector('#computer');
const humanLog = document.querySelector('#human');

//Computer Brain, selects random number between 0-2 and chooses a switch case.
const getComputerChoice = () => {
  let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

  let text = '';
  switch (randomNum) {
    case 0:
      text = `rock`;
      break;
    case 1:
      text = `paper`;
      break;
    case 2:
      text = `scisscor`
      break;
  }
  return text
};

//See's who wins the round
const playRound = (playerSelection, computerSelection) => {
  if (playerSelection === rock && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `You lose Paper beats Rock`;
  } else if (playerSelection === rock && computerSelection === 'scisscor') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `You win Rock beats Scisscor`;
  } else if (playerSelection === rock && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `It's a DRAW!`
  } else if (playerSelection === paper && computerSelection === 'scisscor') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `You lose Scisscor beats Rock`;
  } else if (playerSelection === paper && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `You win Paper beats Rock`;
  } else if (playerSelection === paper && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `It's a DRAW!`
  } else if (playerSelection === scissor && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `You lose Rock beats Scissor`;
  } else if (playerSelection === scissor && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `You win Scissor beats Paper`;
  } else if (playerSelection === scissor && computerSelection === 'scissor') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `It's a DRAW!`;
  }
};

//Adding function togather 
const playerSelection = rock;
const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));

//Calls the playRound() which plays one round to play 5 rounds using for loop
function game() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

section {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

aside {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h4 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

button {
  padding: 5px;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.reset {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="index.js" defer></script>
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
    <h3>First one to 5 wins, wins the game!</h3>
  </div>
  <section>
    <h4>Select Your Play</h4>
    <button class="rock button1">Rock</button>
    <button class="paper button1">Paper</button>
    <button class="scissor button1">Scissors</button>
  </section>
  <aside>
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
    <div id="log"></div>
  </aside>
  <footer>
    <div id="computer"></div>
    <div id="human"></div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Can you clarify the problem and provide either an example output or more clear intended behavior?

Comment: I want the game to work depending on what button the person presses, the problem is idk how to connect the buttons to my function, the only way it works rn is if you manually input the button you want in the JS file.(you can see it in the 'Adding functions together')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to add an event listener with [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). To detect which button is pressed without adding an event listener for each button, you can add an event listener to the parent element of all the choice buttons, then use event propagation. Like this:

```js
const choices = document.querySelector('#choices');
const resetButton = document.querySelector('.reset');
const whoWonTheRound = document.querySelector('#log');
const computerLog = document.querySelector('#computer');
const humanLog = document.querySelector('#human');

//Computer Brain, selects random number between 0-2 and chooses a switch case.
const getComputerChoice = () => {
  let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

  let text = '';
  switch (randomNum) {
    case 0:
      text = `rock`;
      break;
    case 1:
      text = `paper`;
      break;
    case 2:
      text = `scisscor`
      break;
  }
  return text
};

//See's who wins the round
const playRound = (playerSelection, computerSelection) => {
  if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `You lose Paper beats Rock`;
  } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scisscor') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `You win Rock beats Scisscor`;
  } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `It's a DRAW!`
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scisscor') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `You lose Scisscor beats Rock`;
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `You win Paper beats Rock`;
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `It's a DRAW!`
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `You lose Rock beats Scissor`;
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `You win Scissor beats Paper`;
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'scissor') {
    return whoWonTheRound.textContent = `It's a DRAW!`;
  }
};

let gameCount = 0;
choices.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName != 'BUTTON') return;
  if (gameCount++ >= 5) {
    console.log('5 round played. Game is over');
    return;
  }
  playRound(e.target.textContent.toLowerCase(), getComputerChoice())
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

section {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

aside {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h4 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

button {
  padding: 5px;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.reset {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="index.js" defer></script>
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
    <h3>First one to 5 wins, wins the game!</h3>
  </div>
  <section id="choices">
    <h4>Select Your Play</h4>
    <button class="rock button1">Rock</button>
    <button class="paper button1">Paper</button>
    <button class="scissor button1">Scissors</button>
  </section>
  <aside>
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
    <div id="log"></div>
  </aside>
  <footer>
    <div id="computer"></div>
    <div id="human"></div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes! This helped but do you mind explaining why you took off the loop and explain how this particular eventListener works please? Also on  my system the scissors button doesn't seem to be  working

Comment: @Angel94124 Oops, I had a small typo. I've edited my answer and the scissors button now works.

Comment: @Angel94124 I removed the loop because now every time you click the button it runs again and a new computer choice is caluclated, so the loop doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: The event listener works because events on any children nodes will also be events on parent nodes, so we can add an event listener to the parent node to get its children's events. `e.target` is the node of the child element which received the event, so we can check if it is a button and use it's `.textContent`.

Comment: Let's say I select a DIV full of elements all the DIV children will also get events even though I didn't select them?

Comment: @Angel94124 No, events only bubble up the DOM tree. Events of children are also events of their parents, but events of parents aren't events of their children. See [this JSFiddle I made](https://jsfiddle.net/86xscnpq/) for a small example. You can also read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling) for a bit more info (see the Event Bubbling section).

Comment: That example really helped me understand. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of behaviour you could implement a new function, which takes the selection as a parameter.

Create a new function:

```
function playerSelection(selection) {
    if(selection === 'paper') {
        // do something
    }
    if(selection === 'rock') {
        // do something
    }
    if(selection === 'scissor') {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now, you can call the function whenever you click with the onclick event:

```
  <section>
      <h4>Select Your Play</h4>
       <button onclick="playerSelection('rock')">Rock</button>
       <button onclick="playerSelection('paper')">Paper</button>
       <button onclick="playerSelection('scissor')">Scissors</button>
  </section>
```

Comment: It would be better to teach modern coding using `addEventListener()` instead of inline JS.